# how to restrict child control inside Parent control in Winform application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I've created a Label controls dynamically inside Panel control. I'm moving label controls using mouse events. that time label control moving outside the panel control. How can i restrict it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take benefit of `Cursor.Clip` for your requirement (although we can handle this manually in the `MouseMove` event handler):

```
    Point downPoint;
    //MouseDown event handler for your label1
    private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        downPoint = e.Location;
        //this is the most important code to make it works
        Cursor.Clip = yourPanel.RectangleToScreen(new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, yourPanel.ClientSize.Width - label1.Width, yourPanel.ClientSize.Height - label1.Height));
    }
    //MouseMove event handler for your label1
    private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            label1.Left += e.X - downPoint.X;
            label1.Top += e.Y - downPoint.Y;
        }
    }
    //MouseUp event handler for your label1
    private void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        Cursor.Clip = Rectangle.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you add the label to the panel dynamically then you must do:

```
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
```

if you don't, that the mistake. On top of that, when you move the label, make sure that the new values are inside the range of the panel, using

```
panel1.Location.X
panel1.Location.Y
```

and share your code for more help if needed

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the movement by defining the rectangle that the cursor must reside. Use the [Cursor.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip.aspx) method.

Set when dragging:

```
Cursor.Clip = panel1.ClientRectangle;
```

Then with mouseUp event:

```
Cursor.Clip = null;
```

Comment: The idea of using `Cursor.Clip` is OK but to make it what the OP wants, we need more code to handle. `Cursor.Clip` is a `Rectangle`, so we can't set it to `null`.